# What does it mean when you bind something to a timeout?

Tags: jquery

In a sample that I have, they have simulated an ajax-call like this:

```
route('/page1', 'template1', function () {
  this.greeting = 'Hello world!';
  this.moreText = 'Loading...';

  // Simulating an Ajax call which take 0.5 s
  setTimeout(function () {
    this.moreText = 'Bacon ipsum...';
  }.bind(this), 500);
});
```

the bind seem to update "this" and trigger

```
Object.observe(current.controller, current.render.bind(current));
```

that updates a view.

I try to perform the same thing with an actual ajax-call:

```
route('/products', 'item_tmpl', function(){
    this.products = []
    $.getJSON('/data/list.json', function(data){
        this.products = data;
        //var dataObject = { products: data };
    }).bind(this);
})
```

But that returns undefined is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a big problem with `setTimeout`: The callback will be invoked with a wrong `this`. Not the `this` from the function it was called from.

From MDN:

> When you pass a method to setTimeout() (or any other function, for
>   that matter), it will be invoked with a wrong this value.

[Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout#The_.22this.22_problem)

So the author of this code uses [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value

What should solve that problem.

---

```
$.getJSON('/data/list.json', function(data){
        this.products = data;
        //var dataObject = { products: data };
}).bind(this);
```

You are calling `bind` on the return of `$.getJSON`.

But as you can read in the `bind` reference it is a `Function` method. `$.getJSON` returns nothing `undefined`. That's the reason for `undefined is not a function.`

Correct it should look like:

```
$.getJSON('/data/list.json', function(data){
        this.products = data;
        //var dataObject = { products: data };
}.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on the "this" keyword in JavaScript -

here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this